# MongoServerError: Nested BSON depth greater than 50 not allowed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I want to update an object key from mongodb. But when i want to update that key, I am getting this error

```
MongoServerError: Nested BSON depth greater than 50 not allowed
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\Users\Mahabub Saki\Desktop\my-projects\asgmt-11\server-side\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:203:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mahabub Saki\Desktop\my-projects\asgmt-11\server-side\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:63:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\Mahabub Saki\Desktop\my-projects\asgmt-11\server-side\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\Mahabub Saki\Desktop\my-projects\asgmt-11\server-side\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Comment: What is you collection model and query?

Comment: Atlas M0,M2/M5 has BSON Nested Object Depth max 50 levels. [see this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/#operational-limitations) Normally we have max 100 levels, but you really need so much nested documents?